# Why is the output 10 from this JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, nested

Consider:

```js
function hi(a, b) {
  return a * b
}

function hello(a, b) {
  return hi(a, b + 2)
}

console.log(hello(2, 3)); // 10
```

How is the answer 10?

Comment: Your current output appears to be a SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

```
function hi(a, b) {
    return a * b
}

function hello(a, b) {
    return hi(a, b + 2)
}
hello(2, 3)

//10*
```

I strongly believe, the `*` you used in the start is an error so the above is the correct beautified code

You are calling function hello with 2 arguments, `2` & `3` which calls hi function with argument (2, 5) as `3` + `2` is 5

When it will call hi, it will multiple `5*2` which is `10`

Comment: Where did you get the arguments of 2,5 for the hi function?

Comment: You are passing 2, 3 to hello function which is calling hi(a, b + 2)

a = 2
b = 3
hi(2, 3 + 2)  = hi (2,5)

Answer (score 0):

Let's first you understand what you have written by yourself. There are two functions `hi` & `hello`

```
function hi(a, b) {
  return a * b
}

function hello(a, b) {
  return hi(a, b + 2)
}

hello(2, 3)
```

When the following function is executed

1. `hello(2,3)` returns `hi(2,3+2)`.
2. `hi(2,5)` returns `2*5`. Thus the answer is 10.

Answer (score -1):

When you call the function with argument `2` and `3`. These values get assigned to respective parameters.

```
a = 2 and b = 3
```

Then inside the function `hello` you are returning the value of what `hi` function returns with arguments as

```
hi(a, b + 2)
// here what you've passed argument to hi is as follows:
// a => value of a              => 2
// b => value of b + 2 => 3 + 2 => 5
```

so when `hi` executes it returns

```
a * b
2 * 5 = 10
```